# toDataURL not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

I am trying to generate a url for the canvas. Here are the steps I followed:

```
var can = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
var src = can.toDataURL("image/png");
```

When I tried running the above code on firebug it throws an error :

```
TypeError: can.toDataURL is not a function
```

I am running firefox 8 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a [**`NodeList`** *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList), not a single element.

Simply access the first element of the list:

```
var src = can[0].toDataURL("image/png");
```

If you want to get the data URL for each canvas, then you have to iterate over the list. Otherwise, giving the canvas an ID and retrieving the reference with `getElementById` might be more convenient.

Answer (score 8):

Double check you are running `toDataURL()` the canvas object itself, not on the context object.

Answer (score 7):

```
var can = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
```

this returns an array of canvas elements. you need to get the canvas by id.

```
var can = document.getElementById("canvasId");
```

Answer (score 6):

Something not mentioned in the accepted answer: even when using an ID selector, jQuery's Sizzle returns an object/collection. So if you are getting this error while using jQuery, use the `[0]` appendage to access the first index of the element. If you are curious, the indices can be explored by using `console.dir($('#canvasId));`

For example, this perfectly normal selector would fail:

```
var src = $('#canvasId').toDataURL("image/png");
```

But this one would work (notice the extra parenthesis):

```
var src = ($('#canvasId')[0]).toDataURL("image/png");
```

Answer (score 1):

**if you use jquery**

```
var canvas = $('#myCanvasId'); 
var image = canvas[0].toDataURL('image/png');
```

**if you use javascript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvasId');
var image = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

(SOLVED !)
I've encountered with this problem & i solved it . First of ALL you should check that you have included the CDN HTML2CANVAS.js in your script links in your head  tag . To do this you should paste this script in your  head  tag , after the jquery CDN :
(add this script below into your  head  tag )

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

in this CDN , the function 'toDataURL' have been defined & if you go to this link and search (with CTRL+F) on this script page , you could find toDataURL function . (which has been defined in this CDN)
NOW my head tag is like this below and it works :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is helpful for capture canvas image and download from a video.

```
capture() {

  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var canvas = $('#canvas');
  canvas.attr('width', 300);
  canvas.attr('height', 300);
  canvas[0].getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width(), canvas.height());
  console.log(canvas);
  var download = document.getElementById("download");
  var image = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/png");
  download.setAttribute("href", image);
}

<video id="video" width="300">
        <source src="videoURL" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

<a class="cmd-txt tar" href="" id="download" download="download.png">
  <img id="capture" src="src/assets/images/download_black.png" (click)="capture();" class="cursor-pointer" alt="download video image">
</a>

<canvas id="canvas">

</canvas>
```

Comment: Please provide with an explanation of what you're doing

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: In the question, he has given "var src = can.toDataURL("image/png");" Then he is getting an error because he is not taking dataURL form the canvas. In my answer, I have taken the dataURL. I have given download functionality also..